# Aptana 3 intellisense/autocompletion stopped working

Tags: javascript, eclipse-plugin, aptana

I am having a weird problem.

I had first installed Aptana Studio 3 and everything was working as it should have. But then suddenly the autocompletion stopped working. Earlier typing `document.g` would result in showing getElementById (and other methods with starting with g) but suddenly it stopped working. 
Finding no solution to the problem I installed the Aptana plugin for eclipse (3.0.3) and like before after sometime the autocompletion stopped working in eclipse too. Thinking it was some sort of bug I installed the preview release of aptana (3.0.4 beta) but that didn't solve the problem.

Instead of the normal methods (getElementById) I used to get earlier this is what I see now:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFa04.png]

As mention earlier pressing `document.g` doesn't pops up anything (I tried ctrl + space):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bW0Bh.png]

In file association window (prefrences > General > Editors > File Associations) `.js` extension is set to `JavaScript Source Editor`. In Aptana Studio 2 this used to be `Aptana JS editor`.

So how do get it working again?

Comment: One thing, can you try selecting Project->Clean..., select "Clean projects selected below", then make sure the project containing this file is selected, then click OK? If content assist works again, there may be an issue with indexing and type inferencing.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving to a new workspace.. thats what worked for me.

its [bug](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-893?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel) that was fixed but is still sporadic

I tried a few things like re-install but my workspace still had issue. It also may be something wrong with the files in workspace.